# git diff stash@{0}^! does not work since update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, git

In Ubuntu 20.04 (containing Git 2.25.1) I could use this command to show the contents of a stash:

```
git diff stash@{0}^!
```

Since updating to Ubuntu 22.04 (containing Git 2.34.1) this does not work anymore. It simply does not display anything. The following syntax still works:

```
git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0}
```

And the `^!` syntax also still works on commits:

```
git diff f27984d^!
```

or with `HEAD`:

```
git diff HEAD^!
```

Does anybody have an idea why the `^!` syntax does not work on stashes anymore?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Git. I compared Git versions using docker (`docker run -it --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $HOME:$HOME:rw -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v $PWD:$PWD:rw -w $PWD bitnami/git:2.27.0 diff stash@{0}^!`) and the syntax stopped working with Git v2.28.

Comment: You may want to report this bug [to the mailing list](https://git-scm.com/community).

Comment: Yep, I did: https://marc.info/?l=git&m=166297664218037&w=2

Comment: Will `git show stash@{0}` give you what you want?

Comment: @larsks Yes, and so does `git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0}`, which I already mentioned. I'd like this specific syntax to work, though.